# Converting Bing JSON to Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  "SearchResponse":{
  "Version":"2.2",
  "Query":{
     "SearchTerms":"codexperiments"
  },
  "Web":{
     "Total":41,
     "Offset":0,
     "Results":[
        {
           "Title":"Code Xperiments - Because IT is an experimental science",
           "Description":"The deferred-time page scrolling technique I described in my previous article is not what I really wanted to achieve at first. Although powerful, it lacks of “dynamism”.",
           "Url":"http:\/\/www.codexperiments.com\/",
           "CacheUrl":"http:\/\/cc.bingj.com\/cache.aspx?q=codexperiments&d=4548825798150827&mkt=en-US&w=a8960869,c9182d07",
           "DisplayUrl":"www.codexperiments.com",
           "DateTime":"2011-01-14T16:19:00Z"
        }
     ]
  }
}
}
```

I am trying to parse out the title/url using gson

```
public class GoogleResults {

    private ResponseData responseData;
    public ResponseData getResponseData() { return responseData; }
    public void setResponseData(ResponseData responseData) { this.responseData = responseData; }
    public String toString() { return "ResponseData[" + responseData + "]"; }

    static class ResponseData {
        private List<Result> results;
        public List<Result> getResults() { return results; }
        public void setResults(List<Result> results) { this.results = results; }
        public String toString() { return "Results[" + results + "]"; }
    }

    static class Result {
        private String url;
        private String title;
        public String getUrl() { return url; }
        public String getTitle() { return title; }
        public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }
        public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
        public String toString() { return "Results[url:" + url +",title:" + title + "]"; }
    }

    }
```

and

```
GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);
```

but my results are always null.  Any ideas what I am missing??

Comment: Why are you trying to use Google.com JSON format to parse the results of Bing.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to match the data structure to the JSON data structure, otherwise it won't parse correctly. Also, like what the other guy who answered said, name things what they're named in the JSON. As in, remember to capitalize variables if they're capitalized in the JSON.

```
public class Result {
    SR SearchResponse;

    static class SR {
        W Web;

        static class W {
            List<R> Results;

            static class R {
                public String Url;
                public String Title;

                public String toString() {
                    return Url + Title;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return SearchResponse.Web.Results.toString();
    }
}
```